# iOS UiPickerView(-Helper) shall send a message

Tags: ios, delegates, uipickerview

What I am trying to do:

I have a `ViewController`:

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myPicker;
@synthesize myPickerHelper;
@synthesize label;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myPickerHelper = [[UIPickerViewHelper alloc]initWithUIPickerView:myPicker   andNumberOfComponents:4];

    [myPickerHelper.valuesForComponent1 addObject:@"TEST1"];
    [myPickerHelper.valuesForComponent1 addObject:@"TEST2"];
    ;

    [weightsPicker reloadAllComponents];
    [weightsPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    //TODO receive message from picker helper.
  //label.text = ... set a listner (like that one in java) or what else
    }

}
```

And I have a `PickerViewHelper`: (which handles the delegate and datasource issue)

```
@interface UIPickerViewHelper : NSObject <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, OnPickerViewChangeDelegate>

@implementation UIPickerViewHelper 
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  //TODO send message to controller view.
}
```

And the protocol:

```
@protocol OnPickerViewChangeDelegate
@optional
-(void)onChange:(NSString*)result;
@end
```

What I want is to use the protocols method "onChange" in my `UiPickerViewHelper` class, so that my label (in my ViewController) will be informed.
I know how to solve that in Java but I have no idea how to solve that in objective c.

regards

Answer (score 1):

**UIPickerViewHelper.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <OnPickerViewChangeDelegate> delegate
```

**UIPickerViewHelper.m**

```
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //TODO send message to controller view.
    [self.delegate onChange:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Selected row %d", row]];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myPickerHelper = [[UIPickerViewHelper alloc]initWithUIPickerView:myPicker   andNumberOfComponents:4];
    myPickerHelper.delegate = self;

    ...
}

-(void)onChange:(NSString*)result {

    NSLog(@"Here is the result: %@", result);
    label.text = result;
}
```

Comment: OK!!! That works! But i dont understand why... Why does the view controller knows (or can override) the onchange method?

Comment: Because the view controller is conforming to the `OnPickerViewChangeDelegate` protocol means that the view controller has to implement that method. It is not overriding it, it's just implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `UIPickerview` delegate method for change.
Since it will stop at any position and

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

method will be called, so if user exits before picker stops animating/rolling...
the method that hides the `UIPickerView` must call the uipicker for the last selected value while rolling/animating.

```
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
    if(delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onChange:)){
        [delegate onChange:row];//return the index of row selected
     }
    }
```